# Prove $ \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\left(\tfrac{1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right) $does not exist

Tags: limits, analysis

Sorry for my english beforehand. 
I'm not sure if my prove is any good.

f: $ \mathbb{R} \to [-1,1]: x \mapsto cos( 1/(x-\pi/2)) $

reductio ad absurdum:

$ \exists \eta \in \mathbb{R} $ with $ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)=\eta $

$ \Rightarrow \epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \exists \delta >0 $ with
$ \left| f(x)-\eta \right|<\frac{1}{2} \ \ \forall \left| x-\frac{\pi}{2} \right|<\delta$

for $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ choose

$ a_n:= \frac{1+\pi^{2}n}{2\pi n} $

$ b_n:= \frac{1+\pi^{2}n+ \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}} {\pi +2\pi n} $

$ f(a_n)=1 $ and $ f(b_n)=-1 \Rightarrow \left| f(a_n)-f(b_n) \right|=2$

Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\left| a_n - \frac{\pi}{2} \right|<\delta$ and $\left| b_n- \frac{\pi}{2} \right|<\delta$

$ \Rightarrow 2= \left| f(a_n)-f(b_n) \right| = \left| (f(a_n)-\eta)+(\eta-f(b_n)) \right| \\ \leq  \left| f(x_1n)-\eta \right| + \left| f(a_n)-\eta \right| < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 $

$ \Rightarrow 2<1 $ which is not possible

therefore there is no $ \eta \in \mathbb{R} $ : $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} f(x)=\eta $

$ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}cos(\tfrac{1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}) $ does not exist.

Your help would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jaki! You are supposing that the limit exists for your proof, this means that $\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0$... So when you pick $\varepsilon=1/2$, this means that **there exists**  some $\delta>0$ (you wrote that $\varepsilon=1/2$ for $\delta>0$) such that the condition holds whenever $\lvert x-\pi/2\rvert<\delta$ (not when $\lvert x\rvert<\delta$).

Comment: and now? is the prove correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct. But there are some slight changes to be made (just for clarity of the arguments). I'll write them in a separate comment.

Comment: First, I think the notation $x_1n$ a bit confusing, as it looks like you were multiplying $x_1$ with $n$, but as you defined it, it is a sequence. So try to write it as $x_1(n)$ or $a_n$ and the other one as $b_n$. Now, to clarify the part you said you were not too sure about: Both sequences converge to $\pi/2$, and because of this fact, and by definition of the limit of a sequence, for any $h>0$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\lvert a_n-\pi/2\rvert<h$, and similarly for $b_n$.

Comment: So, for the value of $\delta$ that corresponds to $\varepsilon=1/2$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that **for all** $n\geq N$, $\lvert a_n-\pi/2\rvert$ and $\lvert b_n-\pi/2\rvert $ are less than $\delta$. That's why you can choose some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that what you wrote is true. The rest of the proof is great. Hope this helps \ (•◡•) /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Variables twice will give Intuition into the Case.

$\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\left(\tfrac{1}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)$

Substitute $y=(x-\pi/2)$ to get :

$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \cos\left(\tfrac{1}{y}\right)$

Substitute $z=(1/y)$ to get :

$\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \cos\left(z\right)$ [[ Here $z=(1/y)=(1/(x-\pi/2))$ or $x=(\pi/2+1/z)$ ]]

Naturally , this has no limit !

It oscillates ( $+1,0,-1,0,+1$ ) never staying at a limit.

When $Z$ is large ( $z \rightarrow \infty$ ) , we get :
If $\cos{(Z)}=L$ then $\cos{(Z+\pi)}=-L$
If $\cos{(Z)}=0$ then $\cos{(Z+\pi/2)}=\pm1$
If $\cos{(Z)}=+1$ then $\cos{(Z+\pi/2)}=0$
If $\cos{(Z)}=-1$ then $\cos{(Z+\pi/2)}=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately substitution was not allowed by the prof. Should have stated that. Nevertheless your answer helps understanding the underlying problem.